# How can I convert a LOG .txt to .json using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, logging

I'd like to know how can i convert a log to .Json using JS.
Reading the data in the LOG and converting it to .json, i searched a lot and didnt find anything about it.

Comment: Questions on the main SO site need to be in English. You may find better luck with https://pt.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the format of the log.  Typically a call to `JSON.stringify(some_object)` is made but you'd likely need to convert the file to simple objects first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert .txt file to JSON using React and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630654/how-to-convert-txt-file-to-json-using-react-and-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply read from the `.txt` file then write the contents to a `.json` file using `JSON.stringify` to make sure characters such as newlines and double quotes are escaped properly.

For example using Node.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const contents = fs.readFileSync('log.txt', 'utf8');
fs.writeFileSync('log.json', `{ "data": ${JSON.stringify(contents)} }\n`);
```